# Wildcard reference to another workbook with INDIRECT Function

Tags: excel, formula

I want to make a reference to another workbook , let's say its name is "My workbook.xlsm" with the INDIRECT Function in Excel.

However "my workbook" file name could have any other string/characters before it or after it.

let's say I'm Trying to lookup "Lookup Value"

=VLOOKUP("*"&"Lookup Value"&"*",INDIRECT("'["&"*"&"my workbook"&"*"&".xlsm"&"]"&"("&A7&")"&"'!$A:$H"),8,FALSE)

I've tried the above formula and when i remove the wildcards before and after "my workbook" reference and write the name of the workbook exactly as it is , the formula works fine, but when i place the wildcards the formula gives a REF Error.

I'm definitely doing something wrong.

can anyone help please?

thanks in advance.

Comment: With `VLOOKUP(..,..,.,FALSE)` you're looking for an *exact* match; so why use wildcards?

Comment: The wildcard is mainly for the workbook reference inside the INDIRECT function, you can disregard the wildcards around the Lookup value, they aren't important to me, the problem for me is having a wildcard reference for the workbook, that's mainly what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workbook referenced with INDIRECT() must be open for the reference to work. Therefore, this approach is a non-starter from the go, unless you happen to have all files that might potentially meet the wildcard criteria open at the same time with your first workbook.

You may want to have a look at the free add-in called MOREFUNC.XLL, which has a function INDIRECT.EXT() that works with closed workbooks.

Edit: there are no wildcards in your formula above. A wildcard can be a `?` for a single character or a `*` for any number of characters. The wildcard usage for INDIRECT with sheet names is explained in the video in your comment. For your example the formula would look like

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'[*my workbook*.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$H"),8,0)
```

There is no need to split up a string into a series of concatenated strings, but if you do, it does not make a difference.

You will find that this formula will always return an error, though. Indirect cannot parse wildcards in file names. It works fine with sheet names.

[image]

As I said in my comment: Since the file with the lookup table needs to be open anyway, so INDIRECT() can work in the first place, you can use a regular Vlookup with a direct reference to "my workbook". If you rename that file, the Vlookup formula will reflect the change immediately.

Comment: I'm aware that the INDIRECT function needs the workbook to be open and i do leave it open. I've seen a video for on excellsfun channel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCGr58PVJVA that can do wildcard reference for worksheets, it didn't explain it for workbooks though and that's why i thought to ask as i thought it was possible. thanks for your reply teylyn :) . anyone else has any other input?

Comment: If the other workbook is open, why do you need INDIRECT or a wildcard for its file name? Just start writing the formula and click the other file to select the lookup table. If both files are open, you can change the lookup file's file name at any time and it will be reflected in your formula automatically.

Comment: one more mention -- `INDIRECT` only seems to work if both sheets are opened in the _same instance_ of Excel (as in, if you've opened another instance to side-by-side work on two files at once, you'll get a REF error)